# How to change docker installation directory in centos 7 with docker 1.13 version

Tags: docker, centos7

I have enclosed the docker details below,

$ docker info

```
Containers: 3
 Running: 3
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 26
Server Version: 1.13.0
Storage Driver: overlay
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Supports d_type: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 03e5862ec0d8d3b3f750e19fca3ee367e13c090e
runc version: 2f7393a47307a16f8cee44a37b262e8b81021e3e
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 15.51 GiB
Name: docker
ID: WYAF:SDYL:LVAU:OKDP:O6K2:ZLG6:RMIB:SET4:SWGN:6TBR:ST6K:4W55
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

$ docker system df

```
TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE              SIZE                RECLAIMABLE
Images              4                   3                   4.441 GB            -1.644e+09 B (-37%)
Containers          3                   3                   6.867 GB            0 B (0%)
Local Volumes       0                   0                   0 B                 0 B
```

$ df -h

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root   14G   14G  647M  96% /
devtmpfs                 7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    7.8G   25M  7.8G   1% /run
tmpfs                    7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                497M  216M  281M  44% /boot
/dev/sdb                 296G   65M  281G   1% /mnt
overlay                   14G   14G  647M  96% /var/lib/docker/overlay/dfa0c4e618c259bf046b454b27a7963fb31b9d4e95cc745ed28696b0791e3166/merged
shm                       64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/6e978cecc472322ef984cdb73117ed0243eb88c30d37c93827084bec88dcf15a/shm
overlay                   14G   14G  647M  96% /var/lib/docker/overlay/9cdd3dc933f93febccaa7e06ba2f86023d3dd655614be5d9e636ab75f21873f4/merged
shm                       64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/ed44174945e331246f622e42a6ea646504075a91e4922168d895ed295cd24109/shm
overlay                   14G   14G  647M  96% /var/lib/docker/overlay/c2bc2c73f0f3b0e717f8ea134aad8554ebb6b77c2dcfd85e8035a645bf75d074/merged
shm                       64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/26fd8e67dc7da80f6047add17aaddd7f67f763966d4a6b65d08680ac41774a28/shm
tmpfs                    1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/0
```

As we can see the space in root directory is filled up, so i would like to mount the  docker installation directory to `/mnt`. Many suggested to include the -g option, but i couldnt able to provide that option.

Could anyone please help me how to mount to /mnt directory and where to make those changes. I am using centos 7 and i have installed docker with the help of below link  and i have followed exactly the same steps,

https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/centos/

And followed the steps provided here https://forums.docker.com/t/how-do-i-change-the-docker-image-installation-directory/1169

I couldnt find a docker file in `/etc/sysconfig` or in `/etc/default`. Please suggest where to change this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Centos 7 uses systemd, so you can create an override file in `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf` that specifies alternate command flags to pass to dockerd when starting in order to use a directory other than `/var/lib/docker` for your container storage:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --graph=/mnt/docker-data --storage-driver=overlay
```

Another option would be to mount the disk you have mounted at `/mnt` at `/var/lib/docker` directly.

Further details are in the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/).

Comment: Followed the same steps, but couldnt make it work. After adding the property in override.conf, i have started docker using `systemctl start docker`. Still root directory is showed as /var/lib/docker. If i start docker using the command `dockerd -g /mnt/docker-data &`, it seems to be working fine. What is the difference ?

Comment: After adding an override file, you need to reload systemd's config in order for it to take effect. You may need to run `systemctl daemon-reload` and then try restarting docker again via `systemctl restart docker` for the override to be used.

Comment: If you use ` --graph="<path_to_image_storage>"` with **quotes** and docker `V17.X` (no issue previously), then the Docker Root Dir will be as following: `/"/home/docker/"` (from `docker info`)

Answer (score 37):

According to the [Docker Document](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#runtime-directory-and-storage-driver), the **recommended** way is to use the platform-independent `daemon.json` file, which is located in `/etc/docker/` on Linux by default.

Set the following flags in the `daemon.json` file:

```
{
  "data-root": "/mnt/docker-data",
  "storage-driver": "overlay"
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: I tried this answer before and had it fail because I hadn't realized I had to confirm the 'storage-driver' option via 'docker info'. I then was trying the steps in the page at https://sanenthusiast.com/change-default-image-container-location-docker/ and still having difficulty when I came back to this answer. Finding the existing storage driver plus doing the 'systemctl stop docker; systemctl daemon-reload; systemctl start docker; docker info' steps after the 'daemon.json' file creation worked for me and confirmed my choice of root directory.

Comment: For further readers: this solution works for CentOS 7 with docker-ce 19.3

Answer (score 3):

For Centos 7, you should modify file: /etc/sysconfig/docker

```
# Modify these options if you want to change the way the docker daemon runs
OPTIONS='--selinux-enabled --log-driver=journald --signature-verification=false --graph=/new/path/to/docker --iptables=False --storage-driver=overlay'
```

I have also disabled iptables, you can remove it.

Modifying the /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service might be a problem when updating the packages.

Comment: To verify execute command "systemctl stop docker && systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl start docker && docker info"